# R - How do I line up axes between a boxplot and matplot?

Tags: r, plot, axis

I have created a side-by-side plot in `R` where both plots are supposed to use the same y-axis.  However, the plot on the left is a `boxplot` and the plot on the right is a `matplot` and in both plots I have set the same y-axis range `ylim = c(0, YMAX)`.  Unfortunately, as you can see below, these plots do not appear to use the same layout range --- the barplot takes the range right to the edges of the axis whereas the matplot has a buffer at each edge of the axis.  Consequently, the y-axes on the plots do not line up as intended.

```
#Create layout for plot
LAYOUT <- matrix(c(rep(1, 2), 2:3), nrow = 2, ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)
layout(LAYOUT, heights = c(0.1, 1))

#Create plot matrix
par(mar = c(0.5, 2.1, 0.5, 2.1), mgp = c(3, 1, 0), las = 0)
plot.new()
text(0.5,0.5, 'Barplot and Violin Plot', cex = 1.2, font = 2)
par(mar = c(5.1, 4.1, 2.1, 2.1), mgp = c(3, 1, 0), las = 0)

#Generate data for plot
x <- 1:100
y <- rchisq(100, df = 40)

#Generate plots
DENS <- density(y)
YMAX <- 1.4*max(y)
barplot(y, names.arg = x, ylim = c(0, YMAX))
matplot(x = cbind(-DENS$y, DENS$y), y = DENS$x,
        type = c('l', 'l'), lty = c(1, 1),
        col = c('black', 'black'),
        xlim = c(-max(DENS$y), max(DENS$y)), 
        ylim = c(0, YMAX), 
        xlab = 'Density', ylab = '')
```

[image]

How do I adjust this plot to line up the y-axes?  (Ideally I would like the plot on the right to put the ticks right to the edge of the axis just as is the case on the left.)

Comment: Curious about why you use colons at the end of lines in R ?

Answer (score 3):

The comment by [user20650](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2250190/user20650) solves my problem, so I am going to take the liberty of expanding it into a larger answer and linking to some documentation I found on the problem.  According to some [lecture notes](https://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/%7Eihaka/787/lectures-r-graphics.pdf) on the base graphics parameters, some of the base plots in `R` add a 6% buffer beyond the specified axis range by default.  The commands `xasx = 'i'` and `yasx = 'i'` *inhibit* this buffer (on the x and y axes respectively), so that the axis limits go right to the edge of the axis.

Applying this solution to the y-axis in the present problem (we do not apply it to the x-axis, since we want to retain the buffer on that axis) gives the following commands and plot.  As can be seen from the plot, the y-axes in the two plots now line up correctly.  Hooray!

```
#Create layout for plot
LAYOUT <- matrix(c(rep(1, 2), 2:3), nrow = 2, ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)
layout(LAYOUT, heights = c(0.1, 1))

#Create plot matrix
par(mar = c(0.5, 2.1, 0.5, 2.1), mgp = c(3, 1, 0), las = 0)
plot.new()
text(0.5,0.5, 'Barplot and Violin Plot', cex = 1.2, font = 2)
par(mar = c(5.1, 4.1, 2.1, 2.1), mgp = c(3, 1, 0), las = 0)

#Generate data for plot
x <- 1:100
y <- rchisq(100, df = 40)

#Generate plots
DENS <- density(y)
YMAX <- 1.4*max(y)
barplot(y, names.arg = x, ylim = c(0, YMAX))
matplot(x = cbind(-DENS$y, DENS$y), y = DENS$x, yaxs = 'i',
        type = c('l', 'l'), lty = c(1, 1),
        col = c('black', 'black'),
        xlim = c(-max(DENS$y), max(DENS$y)), 
        ylim = c(0, YMAX), 
        xlab = 'Density', ylab = '')
```

[image]